# Importing vector files regardless of having point, line and polygon information using a geopackage in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopackage, vector-layer

How do I import vector files regardless of having point, line and polygon information using a geopackage in QGIS?

I am used to using a geodatabase in ESRI's ArcGIS, but since my mac is not compatible I am using the alternative QGIS and their "geopackage" option. Unfortunately, I see that I have to specify one type of geometry for the whole package, even though the package consists of points, lines and polygons. Is there a way to create a geopackage and simply choose a vector-based option? I don't see that kind of option anywhere

Comment: No, you only specify geometry type for *layers*, and a GeoPackage can have multiple layers. When you create a new GeoPackage *Layer* you will have to specify the geometry type, and the next layer you add to the package can be any other vector type. If this is unclear, please edit your question and show the dialog boxes and menu options you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Drag and drop your geopackage file to the QGIS window and a dialog will allow you the select what kind of data you want to load as layer. As an option, you could just select everything.

[image]

Option 2: Open data source manager, select the geopackage file and again select which layers to load:

[image]

When you create a new layer you want to save to an existing Geopackage, right click the layer / export / Save features as... In the opening dialog window, select the existing Geopackage file, define a new layer name and click OK.

[image]

You can have all kind of geometries (point, line, polygon) as well as raster data and even styles and QGIS projects files in one Geopackage.